# ng build Error in Docker Image

Tags: angular, docker, angular-cli

Let me preface this by saying I can't make the repository public. I'll give as much information as possible to help understand the issue.

I have an Angular CLI generated project, with Angular at version 4.4.6, and both the project and global versions of the Angular CLI at 1.5.5.

[image: package.json]

When I run `ng serve`, `ng build`, `ng build --prod`, or `ng build --env=someEnv`, the project builds just fine. I've removed all errors from the build output locally.

The problem comes when I try to do a multistage Dockerfile image build of the project. Here's the Dockerfile:

```
FROM johnpapa/angular-cli as angular-build
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json package.json
RUN npm install --silent
COPY . .
RUN ng build --prod

FROM nginx:alpine
LABEL author="Preston Lamb"
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY --from=angular-build /usr/src/app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80 443
ENTRYPOINT [ "nginx", "-g", "daemon off;" ]
```

The `johnpapa/angular-cli` base image includes `@angular/cli v 1.5.5`.

That is based off help I received from John Papa in [this repo here](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-cli-docker-ootb). When I try to do the Dockerfile blob, this is the output from that:

[image: docker build output]

Everything goes well until the `ng build --prod`. An error occurs there, but is not very specific. It appears to be some error with the postcss-url library...but I can't be 100% sure of that.

I am at a loss as to what to try next. I've googled the error, but found nothing. Does anyone else know where to start?

If I create a new Angular app from the CLI and use the same Dockerfile to build an image, it works. So it is something in the project, but I don't know where to even look based on the error output.

Comment: Can you share your `package.json` ? Then I can try to repro this (without any code)

Comment: @JohnPapa here is a gist with the package.json: https://gist.github.com/plambhsa/2df35b56f871dff7a8e0ae1527456598

Comment: Copying the dependencies from the package.json, installing them in a new CLI generated app, running `npm install`, and then running the Dockerfile results in a successful build. So I don't know if it pops up after actually importing one or many of the packages, but that's what I found.

Comment: Are you saying it works fine with all those dependencies in a blank CLI app?

Comment: Yes, but only when installing the dependencies but not importing any of them in the project.

Comment: I just tried it had no problems with `ng build --prod` nor with `ng build` (which doesnt do as much shaking out of unused code).

Comment: Can you try without `--prod` , just to see if that works?

Comment: Same result. I just don't know where to look to fix it since it builds in dev and production mode if I run the build in my terminal.

Comment: have you checked your local version of node and npm vs what the docker file uses (v8.9)

Comment: This is one thing that I thought of. But I decided to try the docker build on our build server, and it succeeded. It fails on my local machine, but succeeds there. Not sure what the deal is, but is something I'll look into.